# ElasticSearch, get the field where a text matches

Tags: elasticsearch, field, match

I do index JSON documents, where the structure is 'unknown' and I want to search for content and the result should be the FIELD-NAME where the content belongs to. Any way beside doing a query and then iterating through _source document fields to find it again in the results? I thought also about the precolate feature and generating the queries when indexing a JSON document (but this would create hundrets of queries to check while indexing ...). Maybe there is a simple feature I don't know.

E.g. I know "Main Street" will be stored in the data received (e.g. from a web crawler), but to optimise  the crawler it would be helpful to get a suggestion to crawl only the field "property.address.street". The point is customer might know some sample data set to extract from JSON comming from different sources. To apply this knowledge to already collected data, the relevant field name must be found, especially when you want to make it automatically by provided sample content.

Comment: it's a very old question but anyway I guess that highlighting is the answer., and there is a good explanation here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25537322/find-out-which-fields-matched-in-a-multi-match-query